# How to set width for lighting-button

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, slds

I was able to set background and text color based on slds styling hooks but not sure how to set the width:

```
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="View Details" title="View Details"  class="slds-button slds-button_stretch"></lightning-button>


lightning-button.slds-button {
    --sds-c-button-brand-color-background: rgb(0, 44, 95);
    --sds-c-button-text-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have to vary the width and length of button, You can go for html button inside the lwc (which is basically the slds blueprint as per documentation) and then apply required slds for look and feel, also you can apply own custom css on it for the width of the button.

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" style="width:30px">Brand Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the size of the button. It is always as large as it needs to be. If you need a button that you can exert more control over, you'd want to build your own using the Salesforce Lightning Design System blueprint.